# Distinct content that come from different conditions using Infinite Scroll

Tags: sequelize.js, infinite-scroll, koa, postgresql-9.5

I am using Postgres v9.5, sequelize 3.30.4 and Koa.js 2.3.0; the situation that I am going through is similar to instagram home feed, where the posts come from users that you are following and also hashtags that you are also following.

I can get all the content in one query using an OR condition, example:

```
SELECT DISNTICNT(ID), title, description 
FROM posts 
WHERE creatorID in (1,2,3...) OR hashtags IN ('{sport}','{technology}'...) 
ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC 
LIMIT 10, OFFSET 0;
```

But obviously, from this query I don't have a clue if the post was from the creatorID which in this case is the ID of a user that I am following, or from the hashtags that I am following. I was thinking if there is a way to add a variable or custom column to the query that can identify the source, otherwise I have to make two queries and calculate the limit and the offset which is not what I want to do, or maybe sequelize has some option to join this queries into one and add a column for distinction.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` - in your case if `ID` is the primary key, `distinct` won't remove anything at all

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Note that I am not using the word distinct as a query function, but as in distinct where comes the post, from followers or hashtags.

Comment: But you are using `distinct` inside your query as if it was a function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true because I have to eliminate duplications, the same post could come from a follower and a following hashtag if the follower posts a post with one of the hashtags that I am following, correct me if my logic in this is wrong though.

Comment: As I said: putting parentheses around the primary key column won't change anything. `distinct` is always applied to **all** columns in the select list. And if that contains the PK column, by definition no duplicates will show up (and the `distinct` won't remove anything)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then grouping it by the ID will solve this problem, right ? My intention is to find a way to mark a post as from followers or hashtags on the database level.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make a union of two selections based on the conditions and add the extra columns byHashtag and byFollowing to true or false so that when you loop through the posts you know where it comes from. :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT posts.*, 'false' as byHashtag, 'true' as byFollowing 
    FROM "follows"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON "posts"."creatorId" = "followings"."followerId"
    WHERE "followings"."userId" = 1
    GROUP BY "posts"."id"
    UNION
    SELECT posts.* , 'true' as byHashtag, 'false' as byFollowing 
    FROM "follow_hashtags"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON "posts"."tags" && array(SELECT hashtag::text FROM "followedHashtags" WHERE "followerId" =1)
    GROUP BY "posts"."id"
) posts 
ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```